# How to 'save as' an edited image (png) using a file dialog in tkinter and Pil in Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create an image editor that adds text to an image using pillow. My problem is with saving my edited image so that the user can choose the name of the save file by opening up a save-as dialog. Looking at other questions and answers, I came up with this:

```
def onOpen(self):
        im = Image.open(askopenfilename())
        caption = simpledialog.askstring("Label", "What would you like the label on your picture to say?")
        fontsize = 15
        if im.mode != "RGB":
            im = im.convert("RGB")

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", fontsize)

        draw.text((0, 0),str(caption),(255,0,0),font=font)

        file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".png")
        if file:
            file.write(im)
            file.close()
```

However, I get the following error when running it:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Renee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Renee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\tkinterguitest.py", line 52, in onOpen
    file.write(im)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Image
```

I know the issue is that write can only be used with strings, so is there a command like file.write but for images?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the image through the save method that in Image object:

```
file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".png")
if file:
    im.save(file) # saves the image to the input file name.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! unfortunately i'm still receiving an error. This is the error: 
`TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` which is strange, since I removed the write argument

Comment: specifically it says the error is on line 39, in `onOpen
    im = Image.open(askopenfilename())` and `line 52, in onOpen
    im.save(file) # saves the image to the input file name.`

Comment: I just realized that the problem is in this line: `file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".png", filetypes=(("PNG file", "*.png"),("All Files", "*.*") ))` if i open it with wb instead of w it saves, but without the text i wanted on top of it

Comment: @Renee ,  Instead of `wb` write `a`

Comment: It returned the same error code as it has been. I'm not sure if its significant but if i print the contents of file instead of trying to save it it gives me this: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/Renee/Pictures/testfile.png' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>`

Comment: @Renee , try without writing the mode parameter and with `im.save(file)`

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I think I figured it out now :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I ended up creating each component (the image and text) separately and then saving the final image as a composite.Here is the final code:

```
  def onOpen(self):
        im = Image.open(askopenfilename())
        caption = simpledialog.askstring("Label", "What would you like the label on your picture to say?")
        fontsize = 30
        if im.mode != "RGBA":
            im = im.convert("RGBA")
        txt = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, (255,255,255,0))

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", fontsize)
        draw.text((0, 0),caption,(255,0,0),font=font)



        file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".png", filetypes=(("PNG file", "*.png"),("All Files", "*.*") ))
        if file:
            abs_path = os.path.abspath(file.name)
            out = Image.alpha_composite(im, txt)
            out.save(abs_path) # saves the image to the input file name.
```